# Compounding values when mapping array?

Tags: javascript

I would like to compound values while mapping an array, I tried this but it didn't work:

```
var array = children.map((child, i) => {
    return child.offsetHeight + array[i-1]
})
```

I would like an array that looks like this:

```
[1, 5, 3, 2]
```

to output:

```
[1, 6, 9, 11]
```

Using map is not a requirement. But I don't mind using something more intended than a for-loop.

Comment: What’s the criteria to get that result you intend to get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here an alternative way to other proposals and simple one-liner by using a `forEach`-loop:

```js
let a = [1, 5, 3, 2],
    b = [];

a.forEach((el, it) => { b.push(el + (b[it - 1] || 0)) });

console.log(b)
```

`(b[it - 1] || 0)` covers the first iteration where we would access `b[-1]`

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) :

- `.map( ... )` goes through your array
- `.slice( ... )` cuts a part from your array, from beginning to `i+1`
- `.reduce( ... )` returns the sum of the previously cut array

```js
let children = [1, 5, 3, 2];
var array = children.map((child, i) =>
    children.slice(0,i+1).reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0));
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way:

```js
const input = [1, 5, 3, 2];
const result = input.reduce((arr, x, i) =>
    i == 0 ? [x] : [...arr, x + arr[arr.length - 1]]
, null)

console.log(result);
```

Reduce is better than map here, as you get access to the current state, rather than just the current item or the input array.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, you must check at position `0` that array doesn't exist. This solution avoids using `reduce` and `slice` each step, improving performance;

```js
var children = [1, 5, 3, 2]
var sum = 0;
var array = children.map((child, i, array) => {
    sum = sum + child;
    return sum;
})
console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#reduce`.

```js
var result = [1, 5, 3, 2].reduce((r,v,i) => {
  i ? r.push(r[i-1] + v) : r.push(v);
  return r;
},[]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be a combination of map slice and reduce:

```js
arr = [1,5,3,2]

result = arr.map((elem, index) => arr.slice(0, index + 1).reduce((a,c) => a+c))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with `reduce()` method instead of `map()`. So if current index is not 0 you can take last element from accumulator and add current element.

```js
const data = [1, 5, 3, 2]
const result = data.reduce((r, e, i) => {
  r.push(i ? +r.slice(-1) + e : e)
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

You could also do this with just `map()` method using `thisArg` parameter and storing last value inside.

```js
const data = [1, 5, 3, 2]
const result = data.map(function(e) {
  return this.n += e
}, {n: 0});

console.log(result)
```

Or you could just create closure with IIFE and inside use `map()` method.

```js
const data = [1, 5, 3, 2]
const result = (s => data.map(e => s += e))(0)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Example using `for...of`:

```js
var arr = [1, 5, 3, 2]
var res = []
var c = 0
for (let item of arr) {
  c += item
  res.push(c)
}

console.log(res)
//[1, 6, 9, 11]
```